# Extracting order type from sql parser

Tags: sql, parsing, general-sql-parser

using  `global sql parser (gsp)` for extracting column and sorting type from order sql query and extract and or from where condition

```
SELECT employee_id, dept, name, age, salary
FROM employee_info
WHERE dept = 'Sales' and ID=1
ORDER BY salary, age DESC,ID;
```

I can extracting column name but can extract order type

> 1- how can extract order type?
>
> 2- how can extract and , or from where sql?

Comment: To be honest, if you had written your question in Arabic I would have had an easier time understanding it (I can read Arabic).

Comment: type of order by from selectزاي اقدر استخرج

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what you are trying to find?

Comment: are you use global sql parser

Comment: I want extract type order ASC , DESC from select

Comment: Please include a sample result set of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: column salary age order type DESC

Answer (score 0):

If *pSqlstmt* is *gsp_selectStatement* * then you can do something like this:

```
if(pSqlstmt->orderbyClause != nullptr)
{       
    string sortType;
    int colNumOrderBy = pSqlstmt->orderbyClause->items->length;

    for(int i = 0; i < colNumOrderBy; i++)
    {
        gsp_orderByItem *field = reinterpret_cast<gsp_orderByItem *>(gsp_list_celldata(pSqlstmt->orderbyClause->items->head));

        //get order by column name
        char *sortCol = gsp_node_text(reinterpret_cast<gsp_node*>(field->sortKey)); 

        if(field->sortToken== nullptr)
        {
            //ERROR
        }
        else
        {
            //find out sorting type (ASC/DESC)
            sortType = sortType.substr(0,field->sortToken->nStrLen);
        }

        free(sortCol);
        pSqlstmt->orderbyClause->items->head = pSqlstmt->orderbyClause->items->head->nextCell;
    }

}
```

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to match the question (c++ instead of sql as requested according to the tags)

Comment: @Joe As I know General SQL Parser (GSP) comes with Java, VCL, C# and C++ versions. This is proposed solution for C++.